# $x''+(x^2+2x'^2-1)x'+x=0$ has a non trivial periodic solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm trying to prove that $x''+(x^2+2x'^2-1)x'+x=0$ has a non trivial periodic solution. I've written it as a 2x2 system and found that the only equilibrium point $(0,0)$ is strictly unstable. Therefore I'm trying to find a invariant set that contains the origin so I can apply Poincaré-Bendixson, but I haven't had any luck. Any suggestions? also, do you know of a better way to prove this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original equation can be rewritten as the system
$$
\dot x=y,\quad \dot y=-x-(x^2+2y^2-1)y.
$$
Consider the Lyapunov function $V(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. Its derivative is
$$
\dot V= 2xy-2yx-2y^2(x^2+2y^2-1)=-2y^2(x^2+2y^2-1).
$$
The derivative is nonpositive in the set 
$$D=\left\{
(x,y):\;x^2+2y^2\ge 1
\right\}
$$
thus $V(x,y)$ is nonincreasing along the trajectories in $D$.
Hence, the level set
$$
\Omega_1=\left\{
(x,y):\;x^2+y^2\le1
\right\}
$$
is invariant since no solution can get out of it:
[image]

Comment: Any set $\left\{(x,y):\;x^2+y^2\le r\right\}$ where $r\ge 1$ would be invariant, right?

Comment: @Hans Yes, it is. We just need only one set in order to use the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem, so I didn't point this out.

Comment: I see. What tool do you use to generate this pretty graph?

Comment: @Hans I used MATLAB (the arrows are drawn manually)

Comment: I suspected it was Matlab but was not sure how the arrows were generated. Cool.